# Scala Framework's

Tags: framework, веб-программирование, scala

Какие есть популярные фреймворки для web-разработке на Scala. 
К примеру как Spring для Java.

Comment: начинающему специалисту на заметку: апостроф в английском языке при множественном числе перед s не ставится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, наиболее популярным для Scala на текущий момент является **Play!** (https://www.playframework.com/). Есть ещё **Lift** (http://www.liftweb.net/), но о нём последнее время мало слышно.